# What are the benefits of clover instead of grass lawns?

Tags: gardening, plants

I want to convince my neighbors on the idea of adopting a (white) clover lawn.

1. drought-tolerant green ground cover that uses less water
2. fixes nitrogen from the air for better soil and chokes out weeds
3. compared to grass, only needs to be cut every 2-3 months to keep it tidy (low or no mow)
4. even then only grows about 6" tall while tolerating foot traffic ([quote](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/378/6264))
5. copy of quote from city administrator:

> We have no ordinance prohibiting the planting of a clover lawn.
>
> I’m unsure what height they grow to, just keep in mind we have a height limit of 1 foot for the lawn, and it must be free of noxious weeds (clover, obviously, is NOT a noxious weed).

What other benefits are there?

Comment: The clover that I know pokes-up white flowers and looks like weeds. However, the honey bees like it. Now, wild-strawberry looks more neutral in the yard to me. Something else to consider is fine-fescue which just flops over when it gets too tall. Fine-fescue is said to not like heat but it does seem to like sunlight. Now how is the current lawn removed without too much expense ?

Comment: You just cut the current grass as low as your mower will allow, rake up that and the thatch, and then over-seed it. Last, water for about a week.